# How to show images in a datalist?

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

Can anyone help me in displaying the images in a datalist? Here is my HTML:

```
<td valign="top" align="center">
<asp:DataList ID="SearchResultList" runat="server" Width="100%" 
    RepeatColumns="5" Height="141px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center" style="background-color: #f5f5f5">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                   <a href='<%#getHREF(Container.DataItem)%>'>
                      <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#getSRC(Container.DataItem)%>' />
                    </a>
                &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and this is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GetSearchResult(Request.QueryString["SearchText"].ToString());
    }
}

public void GetSearchResult(string searchText)
{
    string GetSearchResult = "Select Name,Image FROM [PMB_User] where Name like '" + searchText + "%'";

    //ds = UHclass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDS(GetSearchResult);
    dt = UHclass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(GetSearchResult);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        SearchResultList.DataSource = dt;
        SearchResultList.DataBind();
    }
}

public string getHREF(object sURL)
{
    DataRowView dRView = (DataRowView)sURL;
    string Id = dRView["Name"].ToString();
    return ResolveUrl("~/Userpage.aspx?Name=" + Id);
}

public string getSRC(object imgSRC)
{
    DataRowView dRView = (DataRowView)imgSRC;
    string ImageName = dRView["Image"].ToString();
    if (ImageName == "NoImage")
    {
        return ResolveUrl(@"~/UserImage");
    }
    else
    {
        return ResolveUrl("~/UserImage/" + dRView["Image"].ToString());
    }
}
}
```

I'm able to fetch the data but not able to display in a datalist.

Comment: what seems to be the problem here and what have you tried?

Comment: wat m doin is getin the users data from sql database his "name and image" by a search option and the should be diplayrd in a gyperlink with image in datalist......m not havng any errors but m not able to display in datalist

Comment: check generated markup. if it's correct, then there's (likely) a problem with images (wrong url or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code.

`<td align="center" valign="top"><%#getSRC(Container.DataItem)%></td>`

Try above and see what result you get in TD and put the same url in browser to test.

You may get some hint over there.. the path may be wrong and using above you can track.

Comment: "/Profielmaker/UserImage/~/UploadedFiles/ee1f6a99-e539-4ae1-b822-a753c14c8fc7bestfriends-4.gif" i am geting this content in the datalist wat do i do nw?

Comment: ohk i got the images now but i m not geting the name of the user which i should i get in a hyperlink

Comment: Hi Developer Jigar AKA Jack,

I think this is not Accepted answer at all and you can not force any one to accept it.

Remember it again for not ask any one to accept your answer.
Thanks...